# Ruby tutorial Ch9 Exercise #9 - Don't Allow Admin to Delete Themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, railstutorial.org

I am a total newbie to Ruby and Rails which is why I am going through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  I am stuck on Chapter 9, Exercise #9.  I have updated the def destroy code in the Users Controller to:

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  if (current_user == user) && (current_user.admin?)
    flash[:error] = "Can not delete own admin account!"
  else
    user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  end
redirect_to users_path
end
```

This seems to work when I test in the browser by adding the "delete" link to the current_user when admin is logged in.  But the exercise says to write a test first - which I did but does not seem to work.  Here is what I have for the test:

```
describe "as admin user" do
  let(:user_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

  before { sign_in user_admin }

  describe "submitting a DELETE request to destroy own admin account" do
    before { delete user_path(user_admin) }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'delete own admin') }
  end
end
```

Maybe what I am testing should not be tested.  How do you test the modification of the def destroy code in the Users Controller?

Comment: I believe you may have meant Chapter 9 Excercise 10 - at least that's what it is showing as in the live version as of today.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to get the code in the original post to work, but had no luck. Instead, I got it to work like this (got it to fail, then pass). This tests for the proper redirect as well as the correct flash message.

THE TEST : authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
  describe "as admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before { sign_in admin }

    describe "can't delete self by submitting DELETE request to Users#destroy" do
      before { delete user_path(admin) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(users_path), 
                  flash[:error].should =~ /Can not delete own admin account!/i }
    end
  end
```

IMPLEMENTATION : Users#destroy

```
def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if (current_user == user) && (current_user.admin?)
      flash[:error] = "Can not delete own admin account!"
    else
      user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    end
  redirect_to users_path
  end
```

Perhaps the reason the original test wasn't working is because the way we're issuing the request?
I tried adding each of the following individually to the describe block and all failed:

```
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'delete own admin') }

it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'All users') }
```

So, seems like Capybara is not actually redirecting to the page to check for these selectors. I tried 'title' and 'h1', thinking maybe there was some problem with the selector 'div.alert.alert-error' ... but the 'title' and 'h1' failed with same "expected CSS to return something" ...

Anyone know more about how `specify { response.should ... }` style tests work? If they don't follow redirects when they hit the controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to the Rails Tutorial (and Rails in general) and had this same problem, and your question helped me figure out the answer.

I am still not certain why your code fails, exactly, but the following steps definitely worked.

First, modify the test code slightly to use the following structure (here I have left out where to put this describe block - you have the right place already):

```
describe "deleting herself" do
  it "should not be possible" do
    expect { delete user_path(admin) }.to_not change(User, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Note that I am using an expect{} block to track the number of User objects. This definitely causes the tests to go Red (which is good at this point), whereas checking for the Flash will *also* make the test go Red, but checking for the error flash doesn't seem to work here. I really don't know why! Maybe something to do with the double redirect that happens?

Next, write the protection code to make the tests green again. Your code works (I think), but I think my code is a bit more idiomatic in that it uses the session helpers defined earlier in Chapter 9.

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  if (current_user? user) && (current_user.admin?)
    flash[:error] = "You are not allowed to delete yourself as an admin."
  else
    user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed. ID: #{user.id}"
  end
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

This change made my test go 'green' again, which successfully completes Exercise 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth pointing out that in the [tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-administrative_users) under listing 9.43 the partial view in app/views/users/_user.html.erb has a check to prevent showing a 'delete' link for the currently signed-in admin user on the users index page.

So even though a user cannot delete their own account through the web UI, I guess exercise  9.9 goes further in also ensuring there is logic at the controller level in case somebody crafted and sent an http delete request for the current user.

Probably a good practice overall to add these safety guards around your rails apps to prevent any strange bugs cropping up.

Since the filter on the partial view makes it so you would never see the error flash anyway, you could also simplify the User controller's destroy action by removing the 'else'.

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  unless current_user?(user)
    user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
  end
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

Comment: Well put. As far as I can tell it would be illogical to have a flash message show saying "You can't xyz" after a line which prevents 'xyz' from ever happening.

Answer (score 0):

I´m also new in Rails, just doing the tutorial for first time, your posts help me a lot but just to contribute, you don´t really need to check if the user is an admin in the destroy as the destroy will be available only for admin user when adding the line

```
before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy
```

In the user controller.

So it is enough to just ask if is not same as current user

```
def destroy
  usertodestroy = User.find(params[:id])
  if (current_user == usertodestroy)
    flash[:error] = 'Can´t delete own user'
  else
    usertodestroy.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed. ID: #{usertodestroy.name}"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end
```

Also the test should just ask that the count has not change after trying to delete

```
describe "as admin user" do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before { sign_in(admin) }

  it "should not be able to delete itself" do
    expect { delete user_path(admin)  }.not_to change(User, :count) 
  end
end
```

Both do not change the results but they just keep the things simpler.

Why i couldn't really get is why the next code is in any case deleting the user when testing:

```
describe "as admin user" do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before { sign_in(admin) }

  it "should not be able to delete itself" do
    expect { admin.destroy  }.not_to change(User, :count) 
  end
end
```

In my opinion this is calling straight the UsersController so it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: (I'm a Rails newb, but been doing Ruby for a few years...) I think the second version is calling the destroy method of the admin object, not the destroy method of the UsersController instance, and that's why the (admin) user gets destroyed regardless of the code in your controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Despite following the above suggestions my test was *still* not passing, with the error:

```
undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

Which I took to mean there was some problem with logging in since this is only called as part of the before_filter 'admin_user' check.

I was able to solve this by using the non-capybara version of the sign in method

```
before { signin admin, no_capybara: true }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I applied eblume suggestions for good, I have some remarks and a doubt though:

First, the test could be simplified as we don't need to check if the count changes by one unit but if it changes by any number:

```
expect { delete user_path(admin) }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

Regarding the code in the controller, it can also be simplified. As we had coded the following before action for destroy:

```
def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

there is no need to check within the 'destroy' method if the user is admin, it must be admin.

So the if clause becomes:

```
if (current_user? user)
```

My problem now is: I don't understand this code, I don't know what this checking does.

My first try was using the following instead:

```
if (current_user.id == params[:id])
```

But this does not work, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Controller action

```
def destroy
  usertodestroy = User.find(params[:id])
  if (current_user == usertodestroy)
    flash[:error] = 'Can´t delete own user'
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    usertodestroy.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed. ID: #{usertodestroy.name}"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end
```

and test

```
describe "as admin user" do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before { sign_in admin, no_capybara: true }

  it "attempting to delete self" do
    expect{ delete user_path(admin) }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end
```

work for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed and why it works?

Comment: I just compare user who sign in and current user. If it is same person, then he cant delete themself and redirect him to root_url. If not - then current user can delete anyone if have got admin: true property.  And we check this (admin cant delete themself) in test.